# JBoss Wildfly 10 Ear deployment guide needed

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly-10, eclipse-jee, application.xml

I'm can't seem to find a rich source for configuring an JEE EAR deployment on WildFly 10.  I'm still stuck defining the application.xml.

I have this doc - https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+WildFly, and the referenced XSD for application.xml, but I still cannot seem to get the EAR to deploy.  So I basically need information to bridge this document to a real application.

I have the server running; Using Eclipse Neon ; Moved existing JBoss 5.2 app into Enterprise Application Project (i.e. have *Web.war, *EJB.jar, *Connector.rar, *Client.jar).

```
<?xml version "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
<module>
    <resources>
    <resources-root>MyEarClient.jar</resources-root>
    <resources>
    <resources>
    <resources-root>MyEarEJB.jar</resources-root>
    <resources>
    <resources>
    <resources-root>MyEarConnector.jar</resources-root>
    <resources>
</module>
<module>
   <web>
       <web-uri>MyEarWeb.war</web-uri>
       <context-root>MyCompany</context-root>
   </web>
</module>

</application>
```

The error I get when I deploy is:

"ERROR ...MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."WildDLM.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApp.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Faild to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "MyApp.ear"
...
Cause by ...DeploymentUnitProcessingException WFLYEE0053: Failed to parse "/C:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/MyEar.ear/META-INF/application.xml"

I get the same error even if remove the EJB and Connector resources (aka. not using these yet; have dumming package in EJB module.)
I've tried looking through this - https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home
but it's basically empty, and a work in progress.
The /examples directory under the Wildfly 10 installation does not have app code, it seems to be just examples for running the server.

I've tried experimenting with XML elements I see in similar posts on stackoverflow, but it's just a guessing game anymore.

Should I use AS7 documentation?

Any help is appreciated!  I need to get on solid ground because I have more code modules to add and alot of refactoring to do.

Thanks,

Anne

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing two different module concepts here. For the `application.xml` there is no `<resources>` element. It looks like a concept for a `module.xml` which is for JBoss Modules. If you're looking to define your EJB library as module it would look something more like this:

```xml
<?xml version "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
    <module>
        <ejb>MyEarEJB.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>MyEarWeb.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>MyCompany</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

The other two libraries should likely be in the `EAR/lib` directory.